# Unexpected Token Import VueJS / Laravel

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to import a template into my Application I created with VueJS. But I get the message: Unexpected Token Import: `import GISView from './components/GISView.vue';`

The code seems simple enough:

```
import GISView from './components/GISView.vue';
// const GISView = require('./components/GISView.vue');
window.Vue = Vue;
window.Event = new class {
    constructor() {
        this.Vue = new Vue();
    }

    fire(event, data = null) {
        this.Vue.$emit(event, data);
    }

    listen(event, callback) {
        this.Vue.$on(event, callback);
    }
};

window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'gisview': {GISView}
    },
    data: {
    },
    methods: {
        init: function() {
            this.$broadcast('MapsApiLoaded');
        }
    }
});
```

**GISVIEW**

```
<template>
    <h1>Test Header</h1>
</template>
<script>
    import GoogleMaps from '../mixins/GoogleMaps.js';

    export default {
        mixins: [GoogleMaps],
        data: {
            test: 1
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log("test");
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "vue-loader": "^7.3.0",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.1.8",
    "babel": { "presets": [ "es2015" ] }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is inside Google Maps Mixins?

Comment: Do you have a .babel_rc file?